# Webshot custom css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I'm trying to save my website as an image using [WebShot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot) with nodeJs. In the documentation it says that WebShot has customCSS option which lets to apply custom css style to a webpage before taking a screenshot. I would like to use that option but when I try to run my file with node it gives me an error of:

`customCSS:'body {
            ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

My code is as following:

```
var options = {
  siteType: "html",
  //defaultWhiteBackground: true,

  customCSS:"body {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
}"

};

webshot(svgsrc,'graphy2.png',options,function(err) {
if(err) {
                console.log('error saving document', err)
            } else {
                console.log('The file was saved!');
            }
});
```

I can save image with no problem is just that I cannot find a way to apply custom css before saving an image, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead (single quoted and in one line):

```
var options = {
  siteType: 'html',
  customCSS: 'body {background-color: #b0c4de;}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to: [link](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/issues/105) and [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14365)

I found that I needed to specify (for example) :

```
 -webkit-justify-content
```

for:

```
justify-content
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also escape your lines

```
var options = {
  siteType: "html",
  //defaultWhiteBackground: true,

  customCSS:"body { \
    background-color: #b0c4de; \
}"

};
```